# How to send list from action class to jsp page?

Tags: hibernate, jsp, struts2

I am developing a application using struts & hibernate.In this case i wanna display result in jsp page from action class. From action class List store information & that List should be printed on jsp page. But i have only one pojo class which my action class & mapping of hibernate is done in the same class.

index.jsp ->MusicAction->a.jsp

```
package action;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
@Action(value="Music")
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name="item")
@Results({
    @Result(name="success",location="a.jsp"),
    @Result(name="error",location="b.jsp")
 })
public class MusicAction extends ActionSupport 
{

@Id
private int item_no;
private String item_Name;
private String item_type;
private float item_price;

public int getItem_no() {
    return item_no;
}
public void setItem_no(int item_no) {
    this.item_no = item_no;
}
public String getItem_Name() {
    return item_Name;
}
public void setItem_Name(String item_Name) {
    this.item_Name = item_Name;
}
public String getItem_type() {
    return item_type;
}
public void setItem_type(String item_type) {
    this.item_type = item_type;
}
public float getItem_price() {
    return item_price;
}
public void setItem_price(float item_price) {
    this.item_price = item_price;
}




@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    List l =getItem();

    System.out.println("in execute"+l);
    return "success";

}


public List getItem()
{   
    System.out.println("yah i m in getItem");

    Session session=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory().openSession();

    Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();


    MusicAction m = new MusicAction();

    //System.out.println("configured");

    Query query = session.createQuery("from MusicAction");

    java.util.List list = query.list();
    Iterator it=list.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        m=(MusicAction)it.next();

        System.out.println(m.getItem_no()+"| "+m.getItem_Name()+"\t|"+m.getItem_type()+"\t"+m.getItem_price());
    }
    t.commit();
    session.close();


    return list;
   }

   }
```

how to access that List in a.jsp?

Comment: What is the problem do you have?

Comment: hey friend in MusicAction class there is List which contains values. & if execute() method returns true, that values should display on jsp page.

Comment: It's not a problem, because execute method never returns true. and you don't have a JSP page.

Comment: i think u haven't seen, i have given path if execute() method returns success, control goes to the a.jsp page.

Comment: A Struts action should not be an entity, and vice versa. That makes no sense. A Struts action should get and save entities, and make them accessible to the view. Reconfiguring Hibernate each time your action is called is also something you should really not do. The session factory must be created once, and only once, for the whole duration of the application.

Comment: what should i do for that-to create session factory only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are explained exact error.so,try this,

MusicAction.class

```
    public class MusicAction extends ActionSupport 
   {
    private List<Item> item=new ArrayList<Item>();//setter method.
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
      System.out.println("in execute"+item.size());
       return "success";
    }
    public List<Item> getItem(){ try{
            System.out.println("yah i m in getItem");
            Session session=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
            MusicAction m = new MusicAction();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from MusicAction");
            item = (List<Item>)query.list();
            t.commit();
            session.close();}catch(Exception e){}
         return item;}
    }
```

a.jsp

```
  <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
  <s:iterator value="item"> 
      <s:property value="item_no" />
      <s:property value="item_Name" />
      <s:property value="item_type" />
      <s:property value="item_price" />
  </s:iterator>
```

Comment: Thanks for it but it throws another exception like  org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(list)]